# How do I mirror (synchronize) panels in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I'd like that whatever I do on a panel to be copied on other panels simultaneously.

For example, I'd like to ssh to multiple similar servers and execute identical tasks in all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by panels you mean panes, doing

```
<prefix> :setw synchronize-panes on
```

will enable the feature you want.

---

If you want to turn it off after you are done doing what you want,

```
<prefix> :setw synchronize-panes off
```

Comment: I found out that one can omit on/off. That is, `:setw synchronize-panes`  will toggle your current behaviour.